# Measuring document cluster cohesion

Tags: clustering, text-mining

I have a set of clusters which each cluster contains a list of short documents. I want to compute how coherent and cohesive each cluster is and filter out the incoherent and in-cohesive ones.

I am aware of **intra-cluster distance** and **within-cluster dispersion**, which are part of computing clustering evaluation metrics **Silhouette Coefficient** and **Calinski-Harabaz Index**, respectively. My question is, is there any other metrics or ways to compute such intra-cluster coherence or cohesion? Is there any standard ways for this that I am not aware of? Thanks.